# Python decorator on instance method

Tags: python, oop, decorator, instance-methods

Anyone know what is wrong with this code?

```
def paginated_instance_method(default_page_size=25):
    def wrap(func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def inner(self, page=1, page_size=default_page_size, *args, **kwargs):
            objects = func(self=self, *args, **kwargs)
            return _paginate(objects, page, page_size)
        return inner
    return wrap

class Event(object):
    ...
    @paginated_instance_method
    def get_attending_users(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return User.objects.filter(pk__in=self.attending_list)
```

I get the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/Users/zarathustra/Virtual_Envs/hinge/hinge_services/hinge/api/decorators.py", line 108, in wrap
        def inner(self, page=1, page_size=default_page_size, *args, **kwargs):
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/functools.py", line 33, in update_wrapper
        setattr(wrapper, attr, getattr(wrapped, attr))
    AttributeError: 'Event' object has no attribute '__name__'
```

The reason why I thought this would work is because, through trial and error, I got the following decorator working like a charm for classmethods:

```
def paginated_class_method(default_page_size=25):
    def wrap(func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def inner(cls, page=1, page_size=default_page_size, *args, **kwargs):
            objects = func(cls=cls, *args, **kwargs)
            return _paginate(objects, page, page_size)
        return inner
    return wrap
```

Comment: Your decorator doesn't make sense.  The decorator is supposed to take a function as an argument, but yours takes only one argument, which apparently a number (`default_page_size`).  Were you intending to decorate with something like `@paginated_instance_method(10)`?

Comment: @BrenBarn Yes, I was trying to do just that.  I am new to decorators, but I'll add an edit to explain why I thought it would work.

Comment: Can you show how you used that other decorator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your decorator has an extra level of indirection which is throwing things off.  When you do this:

```
@paginated_instance_method
def get_attending_users(self, *args, **kwargs):
    return User.objects.filter(pk__in=self.attending_list)
```

You are doing this:

```
def get_attending_users(self, *args, **kwargs):
    return User.objects.filter(pk__in=self.attending_list)
get_attending_users = paginated_instance_method(get_attending_users)
```

That is what decorators do.  Note that `paginated_instance_method` is called with `get_attending_users` as its argument.  That means that in your decorator, the argument `default_page_size` is set to the function `get_attending_users`.  Your decorator returns the function `wrap`, so `get_attending_users` is set to that `wrap` function.

Then when you then call `Event().get_attending_users()` it calls `wrap(self)`, where `self` is your Event instance.  `wrap` is expecting the argument to be a function, and tries to return a new function wrapping that function.  But the argument isn't a function, it's an `Event` object, so `functools.wrap` fails when trying to wrap it.

I have a hunch that what you're trying to do is this:

```
@paginated_instance_method()
def get_attending_users(self, *args, **kwargs):
    return User.objects.filter(pk__in=self.attending_list)
```

That is, you want `paginated_instance_method` to take an argument.  But even if you want to use the default value of that argument, you still have to actually *call* `paginated_instance_method`.  Otherwise you just pass the method as the argument, which is not what `paginated_instance_method` is expecting.

The reason it "worked" for a classmethod is that a classmethod takes the class as the first argument, and a class (unlike an instance) *does* have a `__name__` attribute.  However, I suspect that if you test it further you'll find it's not really doing what you want it to do, as it's still wrapping the class rather than the method.

Comment: It had the parentheses in the other usage -- that was the important difference.  So it never really "worked" for the paginated_class_method.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

`paginated_instance_method` is not a decorator, it is a function that *returns* a decorator. So

```
@paginated_instance_method()
def get_attending_users(self, *args, **kwargs):
```

(Note the parentheses.)

Answer (score 0):

This is really easy, but tricky at first view. Look at [pep 318](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/#current-syntax).

```
@dec2
@dec1
def func(arg1, arg2, ...):
    pass
```

This is equivalent to:

```
def func(arg1, arg2, ...):
    pass
func = dec2(dec1(func))
```

You have an extra wrapper, which takes a decorator's args to use it in the wrapped functions ([closure design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_programming%29)). So your decorator will look like this:

```
@dec(arg=True)
def func(arg1, arg2, ...):
    pass
```

Equivalent to:

```
def func(arg1, arg2, ...):
    pass
func = dec(arg=True)(func)
```