# How can I decorate an instance method with a decorator class?

Tags: python, class, self, python-decorators

Consider this small example:

```
import datetime as dt

class Timed(object):
    def __init__(self, f):
        self.func = f

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        start = dt.datetime.now()
        ret = self.func(*args, **kwargs)
        time = dt.datetime.now() - start
        ret["time"] = time
        return ret

class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Test, self).__init__()

    @Timed
    def decorated(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print(self)
        print(args)
        print(kwargs)
        return dict()

    def call_deco(self):
        self.decorated("Hello", world="World")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    t = Test()
    ret = t.call_deco()
```

which prints

```
Hello
()
{'world': 'World'}
```

Why is the `self` parameter (which should be the Test obj instance) not passed as first argument to the decorated function `decorated`?

If I do it manually, like :

```
def call_deco(self):
    self.decorated(self, "Hello", world="World")
```

it works as expected. But if I must know in advance if a function is decorated or not, it defeats the whole purpose of decorators. What is the pattern to go here, or do I misunderstood something?

Comment: A quick google turns up this: http://thecodeship.com/patterns/guide-to-python-function-decorators/ (see the section "Decorating methods")

Comment: Have you read e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/2365701/3001761, http://stackoverflow.com/q/15098424/3001761

Comment: You won’t run into this kind of problem when you use a function as the decorator instead of a callable object.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

**tl;dr**

You can fix this problem by making the `Timed` class a [descriptor](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-descriptor) and returning a partially applied function from `__get__` which applies the `Test` object as one of the arguments, like this

```
class Timed(object):
    def __init__(self, f):
        self.func = f

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print(self)
        start = dt.datetime.now()
        ret = self.func(*args, **kwargs)
        time = dt.datetime.now() - start
        ret["time"] = time
        return ret

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        from functools import partial
        return partial(self.__call__, instance)
```

---

**The actual problem**

Quoting Python documentation for [*decorator*](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-decorator),

> The decorator syntax is merely syntactic sugar, the following two function definitions are semantically equivalent:
>
> ```
> def f(...):
>     ...
> f = staticmethod(f)
>
> @staticmethod
> def f(...):
>     ...
> ```

So, when you say,

```
@Timed
def decorated(self, *args, **kwargs):
```

it is actually

```
decorated = Timed(decorated)
```

only the function object is passed to the `Timed`, **the object to which it is actually bound is not passed on along with it**. So, when you invoke it like this

```
ret = self.func(*args, **kwargs)
```

`self.func` will refer to the unbound function object and it is invoked with `Hello` as the first argument. That is why `self` prints as `Hello`.

---

**How can I fix this?**

Since you have no reference to the `Test` instance in the `Timed`, the only way to do this would be to convert `Timed` as a *descriptor class*. Quoting the documentation, [Invoking descriptors](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#invoking-descriptors) section,

> In general, a descriptor is an object attribute with “binding behavior”, one whose attribute access has been overridden by methods in the descriptor protocol: `__get__()`, `__set__()`, and `__delete__()`. If any of those methods are defined for an object, it is said to be a descriptor.
>
> The default behavior for attribute access is to get, set, or delete the attribute from an object’s dictionary. For instance, `a.x` has a lookup chain starting with `a.__dict__['x']`, then `type(a).__dict__['x']`, and continuing through the base classes of `type(a)` excluding metaclasses.
>
> However, **if the looked-up value is an object defining one of the descriptor methods, then Python may override the default behavior and invoke the descriptor method instead**.

We can make `Timed` a descriptor, by simply defining a method like this

```
def __get__(self, instance, owner):
    ...
```

Here, `self` refers to the `Timed` object itself, `instance` refers to the actual object on which the attribute lookup is happening and `owner` refers to the class corresponding to the `instance`.

Now, when `__call__` is invoked on `Timed`, the `__get__` method will be invoked. Now, somehow, we need to pass the first argument as the instance of `Test` class (even before `Hello`). So, we create another partially applied function, whose first parameter will be the `Test` instance, like this

```
def __get__(self, instance, owner):
    from functools import partial
    return partial(self.__call__, instance)
```

Now, `self.__call__` is a bound method (bound to `Timed` instance) and the second parameter to `partial` is the first argument to the `self.__call__` call.

So, all these effectively translate like this

```
t.call_deco()
self.decorated("Hello", world="World")
```

Now `self.decorated` is actually `Timed(decorated)` (this will be referred as `TimedObject` from now on) object. Whenever we access it, the `__get__` method defined in it will be invoked and it returns a `partial` function. You can confirm that like this

```
def call_deco(self):
    print(self.decorated)
    self.decorated("Hello", world="World")
```

would print

```
<functools.partial object at 0x7fecbc59ad60>
...
```

So,

```
self.decorated("Hello", world="World")
```

gets translated to

```
Timed.__get__(TimedObject, <Test obj>, Test.__class__)("Hello", world="World")
```

Since we return a `partial` function,

```
partial(TimedObject.__call__, <Test obj>)("Hello", world="World"))
```

which is actually

```
TimedObject.__call__(<Test obj>, 'Hello', world="World")
```

So, `<Test obj>` also becomes a part of `*args`, and when `self.func` is invoked, the first argument will be the `<Test obj>`.

Comment: Why using a `functool.partial` instead of the builtin dedicated `types.MethodType` ?

Comment: Thank you for this comprehensive answer - I'm going to have to read it a few times to grok it, but I'm confident that I will!

When I first tried applying this, I left off the `(object)` in the definition of my decorator - so, I just had `class Timed:` - and I still got the OP's original error. Could you point me at the right concept to read up on to understand why?

Comment: @scubbo - Were you in Python2.7? In 2.7 you want to make sure every class inherits from `object`; this inheritance is default in Python3. I don't know *specifically* why this manifested in a bug, but that's the likely culprit - `type(YourClass)` should be `type`, not `classobj`.

Comment: Can you please explain why 

```def check_authorization(f):
    def wrapper(*args):
        print(args[0].url)
        return f(*args)
    return wrapper

class Client(object):
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.url = url

    @check_authorization
    def get(self):
        print('get')

```
works here? wouldn't it be also unbound?

Comment: Some great docs on the relationship between self, decorators, descriptors, functions, and methods can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) (if you are just interested in the section on functions and methods, check [here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#functions-and-methods)). It definitely helped by understanding.

Comment: I have been struggling to get this to work when you have a decorator that takes in parameters. Do you have any thoughts on how to make this work with, for example `@Timed(interval=5)`?

Comment: is there a way to add arguments to `Timed` object so we can do something like `@Timed(some_init_arg)`?

Comment: I made a Notebook that shows how one could use a Decorator with custom arguments https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1-17Rf-mpxqiN064Ni0TjHddX8Z5fz4ZV?usp=sharing

It does work but I am not sure if this is the best approach for solving the issue.

Comment: I just made a copy of your drive, hope it would work https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1UOTgYsdNpRpdEA16Rl7Jj8LXTYdQI1Zd#scrollTo=-pkuq55Xsmi9 @PythonF

Answer (score 14):

You first have to understand [how function become methods and how `self` is "automagically" injected](https://wiki.python.org/moin/FromFunctionToMethod).

Once you know that, the "problem" is obvious: you are decorating the `decorated` function with a `Timed` instance - IOW, `Test.decorated` is a `Timed` instance, not a `function` instance - and your `Timed` class does not mimick the `function` type's implementation of the `descriptor` protocol. What you want looks like this:

```
import types

class Timed(object):
    def __init__(self, f):
        self.func = f

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        start = dt.datetime.now()
        ret = self.func(*args, **kwargs)
        time = dt.datetime.now() - start
        ret["time"] = time
        return ret

   def __get__(self, instance, cls):           
       return types.MethodType(self, instance)
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped. One note though, this doesn't work in Python 3, since unbound methods no longer exist (`MethodType` only takes two arguments, and the second must not be None). For Python 3 the alternative would be: `return types.MethodType(self, instance) if instance else self`.

Comment: @Dário That should probably be `if instance is not None else`. Don't want to trigger the `else` just because `instance` happens to be falsy.

Comment: Indeed @DominickPastore.

Answer (score 2):

I combined some answers and comments, especially from @PythonF, who had a google collab link that was pretty helpful in seeing how different methods actually work. My aim is not to be the best answer out there, because others know far better, but despite all of the other great answers, no one actually answered the question with code that is complete and reuseable, so here's some minimal code with test cases.

This can accept arguments and passes the instance in properly:

```py
    class Decorator:
        def __init__(self, func = None, start_text = "Start", stop_text = "Stop"):
            self.func = func
            self.instance = None
            self.start_text = start_text
            self.stop_text = stop_text
    
        def __call__(self, func):
            if self.func is None:
                self.func = func
            def call(*args, **kwargs):
                if self.instance is None and len(args) > 0:
                    self.instance = args[0]
                # do stuff before
                print(f"--- {self.start_text} ---")
                wrapped_method = self.func(self.instance, *args[1:], **kwargs)
                # do stuff afterwards
                print(f"--- {self.stop_text} ---")
                return wrapped_method
            return call
    

    class HelloWorld:
        def __init__(self):
            self.test = "test"
    
        @Decorator(start_text="Starting...", stop_text="Done")
        def print(self, name):
            print(name)
            print(self.test)
            return 42


    hello_world = HelloWorld()
    hello_world.print("Max Musterman")
```