# Using a decorator that returns a class on a method?

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

I currently have a decorator that wraps a function into a class.

(We are currently using this weird, custom async framework where each async call is defined as a class with a ton of boilerplate code. My idea was to just decorate functions and then return the appropriate class.)

This decorator works fine on functions outside of classes. However, when using it with methods, the `self` argument is no longer implicitly passed, and I'm not sure why.

Here is the best example I could put together

```
from __future__ import print_function

import functools


def test_wrap(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print("Args:", args)
        print("Kwargs:", kwargs)
        func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper


def test_class_wrap(func):
    """Return a Command object for use with the custom framework we are using."""
    @functools.wraps(func, assigned=('__name__', '__module__'), updated=())
    class Command(object):
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            print("Args:", args)
            print("Kwargs:", kwargs)
            func(*args, **kwargs)

    return Command


class MyObject(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.value = 100

    @test_wrap
    def foo(self):
        print(self.value)

    @test_class_wrap
    def bar(self):
        print(self.value)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    obj = MyObject()
    obj.foo()

    print()
    obj.bar(obj)  # works
    # obj.bar()  # TypeError: bar() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
    # Why is self implicitly passed as an argument like with outher methods?

# Output
# Args: (<__main__.MyObject object at 0x7fe2bf9bb590>,)
# Kwargs: {}
# 100

# Args: (<__main__.MyObject object at 0x7fe2bf9bb590>,)
# Kwargs: {}
# 100
```

Comment: Well. . . think about how this would work if you did it manually.  Without the decorator, were you writing code that had one class nested inside another?  If so, how did you do that?  Classes aren't methods so if you have a decorator that replaces a method with a class, you'll have a class inside your other class, which is a somewhat unusual situation in Python.  Can you show an example of how you would write `MyObject` and `bar` "manually", without using the decorator?

Comment: This question is more focused towards why `self` isn't implicitly passed to `bar`. The code above replicates the problem, not the actual usage. I can try to add an example, but don't expect it to make much sense

Comment: The reason self isn't passed is because there is no instance of your class.  `self` refers to the instance, so it can only be passed when you call a method on an instance, but your `obj.bar` is the *class* called `Command`.  If you wrote that Command class separately and tried to call `Command()`, you would get the same error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I decorate an instance method with a decorator class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30104047/how-can-i-decorate-an-instance-method-with-a-decorator-class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`test_class_wrap` does nothing, just returning a class so `__init__` isn't called. Try to wrap the class with a function passing args and kwargs:

```
def test_class_wrap(func):
    """Return a Command object for use with the custom framework we are using."""
    @functools.wraps(func, assigned=('__name__', '__module__'), updated=())
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        class Command(object):
            def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
                print("Args:", args)
                print("Kwargs:", kwargs)
                func(*args, **kwargs)
        return Command(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    obj = MyObject()
    obj.foo()

    print()
    obj.bar()
```

Comment: I guess this might "fix" it, but it's not clear how.  This will just mean that `obj.bar()` returns the Command class, whereas right now the value of `obj.bar` is the Command class.  So `obj.bar()` won't "do" anything; it will just return a class.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is just what I needed. It passes all my existing tests too. @BrenBarn The goal was the instantiate the class when calling `bar()`. Its a crappy, non-obvious design but I don't have much say in changing it. That is why I'm trying to wrap everything and make it easier to deal with.