# Why is 'self' not in args when using a class as a decorator?

Tags: python, methods, decorator

The top answer for [Class method decorator with self arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11731136/class-method-decorator-with-self-arguments) (direct link to answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11731208) describes how a decorator can access attributes of the object when decorating a method.

I tried to apply this to my own code, but realized it only works when using a function as the decorator. For some reason, when using a class as the decorator, the arguments tuple no longer contains the `self` object. Why does this happen, and is there some other way to access the wrapped method's `self`?

To demonstrate:

```py
import functools


class DecoratorClass:
    def __init__(self, func):
        functools.update_wrapper(self, func)
        self.func = func                    
                        
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("args:", args)            
        print("kwargs:", kwargs)
        print("Counting with:", args[0].name)
        self.func(*args, **kwargs)           
                                  

def decorator_func(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print("args:", args)     
        print("kwargs:", kwargs)
        print("Counting with:", args[0].name)
        func(*args, **kwargs)                
    return wrapper           
                  

class Counter:
    def __init__(self, name, count):
        self.name = name            
        self.count = count
                          
    @decorator_func
    def count_a(self):
        for i in range(self.count):
            print(i)               
                    
    @DecoratorClass
    def count_b(self):
        for i in range(self.count):
            print(i)               
                    

c = Counter('my counter', 3)
                            
c.count_a()
print()    
c.count_b()
```

Output:

```
args: (<__main__.Counter object at 0x7f4491a21970>,)
kwargs: {}
Counting with: my counter
0
1
2

args: ()
kwargs: {}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test2.py", line 48, in <module>
    c.count_b()
  File "./test2.py", line 14, in __call__
    print("Counting with:", args[0].name)
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a known problem (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30105234/10237506)). I actually ran into this same issue when implementing a class decorator in one of my projects a while back.

To fix, I added the below method to my class - which you can also add to your `DecoratorClass`, and then it should all work without surprises.

```
def __get__(self, instance, owner):
    """
    Fix: make our decorator class a decorator, so that it also works to
    decorate instance methods.
    https://stackoverflow.com/a/30105234/10237506
    """
    from functools import partial
    return partial(self.__call__, instance)
```

Also, do see the linked SO answer for an example of why this is.

Comment: Oh, good find, I voted to close this as duplicate.

Comment: yes, i unfortunatley don't know if im able to do that. I would have also voted to close it as a duplicate as well.